# UICollectionviewCell always placing at the edge of the view

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

my `UICollectionViewCell`s are always placing at the edges of the `UICollectionView`. There is a middle space always like this.
[image]

What is the reason for that? And I want to keep 3 items per row always. But in this way it just set 2. How to fix this issue?
Please help me.
Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical //.horizontal
    layout.itemSize = cellSize
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 1, bottom: 1, right: 1)
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing=1.0

    btncollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
    btncollectionView.reloadData()
```

Comment: looking not in detail, seems that your `UICollectionView` width can't afford with 3 columns using this `UICollectionViewCells` width. Are you setting the right width and constraints for that ?

Comment: I have added a sub view with leading and trailing 50,, and my collectionview all 4 sides set to 0 constraints and my cell size is (self,view,size.width-100)/3

Answer (score 0):

**Works for both horizontal and vertical scroll directions, and variable spacing**

Declare number of cells you want per row

```
let numberOfCellsPerRow: CGFloat = 3
```

Configure `flowLayout` to render specified `numberOfCellsPerRow`

```
if let flowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    let horizontalSpacing = flowLayout.scrollDirection == .vertical ? flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing : flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing
    let cellWidth = (view.frame.width - max(0, numberOfCellsPerRow - 1)*horizontalSpacing)/numberOfCellsPerRow
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
}
```

Comment: can you see my update,, I have set those but still same

Comment: whats the value of `cellSize`?

Comment: width =height=104.666

Comment: it should not be a constant value, you need to calculate as I do above

Comment: I said the current value. Im calculating it  (self.view.size.width-100)/3

Comment: you are calculating a total of 100 spacing for each row, whats the problem then?

Comment: How to remove the gap in between 2 items. Its always like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145585/discussion-between-joze-ws-and-randi).